# Is it possible to lock some table records in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to make a row lock in BigQuery? I mean command like

```
select xxx from table yyyy for update;
```

Comment: Can you state the goal? Would help with alternate strategies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, BigQuery doesn't have any concept of `rowlocks`, nor indexes for that matter. Don't think of it like a traditional relational DB.

[Also](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-12-components-of-google-bigquery-c2b49829a7c7):

> Queries see storage at a snapshot in time. They are thus immune to
>   race conditions, table/row/cell locks, halfway states, whatever.